# How to combine own C-extension in own Python Package

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-extensions

I created own Python Package in which I want to add own Python C Extension, because in Python Package I'm importing this C-Ext.
I want to install it from local files, not pypi.
I have dist files of C Extension, and I wonder how to do it properly. I assume that I should do some configuration in setup.py.
Maybe something like [Extension](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) object where I can define own source for package?

```
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=[Extension('ownpackage', '/package.tar.gz')],
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found the answer. Just add source files to project dir and `setup.py`

```
Extension("c_ext", ["module/c_exts/main.c", ...]),
```

Then build module.